# If $\mathrm i\overline A^\top=A$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ have same real and imaginary part

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can we show that if $\mathrm i\overline A^\top=A$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ have same real and imaginary part?

---

I came across this when studying random matrices $A$ of the form $A=X+\mathrm iX^\top$ for real (random) square matrices $X$. Their eigenvalues $\lambda$ all seem to satisfy $\Re(\lambda)=\Im(\lambda)$.

I was able to show that if $\lambda_1+\mathrm i\lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then so is $\lambda_2+\mathrm i\lambda_1$. How can one continue?

Comment: If $Ax=\lambda x$  ($ x \neq 0$)then $i\overline {\lambda}x=\lambda x$ which implies that real part of $\lambda$ equals its imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $iA^\ast=A$, then $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$, i.e. $A$ is normal. Therefore $A$ can be unitarily diagonalised as $UDU^\ast$. The condition $iA^\ast=A$ hence gives $iD^\ast=D$. Therefore $\Re(d_{ii})=\Im(d_{ii})$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 2):

With the inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$:

If $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a unit eigen vector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = a + i b$:
\begin{align*}
\lambda = \langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle \bar{A}^T x , x \rangle = \langle -i \left( i \bar{A}^t\right)x , x \rangle = \langle-i \lambda x , x \rangle = \overline{-i \lambda} . 
\end{align*}
Hence we have $a + ib = \overline{-ia + b} = b + ia$. Thus $a = b$.